# How to use Data.Binary.BitPut

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to pack data (:: [DnsMessage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dns-2.0.1/docs/Network-DNS-Types.html#g:5)) into ByteString. From a little web search, I learned I can pack data like Bool or Int into ByteString by using Data.Binary.BitPut Library. Now I'm struggling with passing an argument.

This code works fine.

```
import qualified Data.Binary.BitPut as BP
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BSI

main :: IO()
main = do
  let res = BP.runBitPut makePacket
  print res

makePacket :: BP.BitPut
makePacket = do
  BP.putBit True
  BP.putNBits 7 $ BSI.c2w 'A'
  BP.putByteString $ BS.pack $ map BSI.c2w "AAAA"
```

Now I want to do like this.

```
defaultQuery :: DnsMessage

main :: IO()
main = do
  let res = defaultQuery BP.runBitPut makePacket
  print res

makePacket :: DnsMessage -> BP.BitPut
makePacket msg = do
  BP.putBit $ foo msg
  BP.putNBits 5 $ bar msg
  BP.putByteString ...
```

How can I make this work ?

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-strict-0.4.8.3/docs/Data-Binary-BitPut.html

```
data DnsMessage = DnsMessage {
  header      :: DnsHeader,
  question    :: DnsQuestion,
  answer      :: [DnsResourceRecord],
  authority   :: [DnsResourceRecord],
  additional  :: [DnsResourceRecord]
}

data DnsHeader = DnsHeader {
  mid     :: Word16,
  flags   :: DnsFlags,
  qdcount :: Word16,
  ancount :: Word16,
  nscount :: Word16,
  arcount :: Word16
}

data DnsFlags = DnsFlags {
  isres   :: Bool,
  opcode  :: Word8,
  aa      :: Bool,
  tc      :: Bool,
  rd      :: Bool,
  ra      :: Bool,
  z       :: Word8,
  rcode   :: Word8
}

data DnsQuestion = DnsQuestion {
  qname   :: [Word8],
  qtype   :: Word16,
  qclass  :: Word16
}

--The answer, authority, and additional sections all share this format
data DnsResourceRecord = DnsResourceRecord {
  rrname        :: [Word8],
  rrtype        :: Word16,
  rrclass       :: Word16,
  rrttl         :: Word32,
  rdatalength   :: Word16,
  rdata         :: [Word8]
}
```

Comment: `foo`, `bar`, `...` - I guess you'll have to try to put it into some more words - I see no way to actually find the question or the problem here as obviously this will not compile

Comment: Thank you, I added some more explanation.

Comment: You will have to keep extracting the constituent parts of the `DnsMessage` and serialising the primitive types they are made out up of (`Bool`, `Int`, ...). Do you need to serialise it to a particular binary format, or are you also in control of the deserialiser too?

Comment: Yes I do need to serialize this to a particular binary format because I am writing a DNS cache client program, and Yes I am in control of the deserializer.